# Running two containers on a single macvlan IP?

Tags: docker

I've been doing some experimenting with Docker and Portainer on Ubuntu Server, and I had a use case pop up that I was curious to know if it would be possible to implement.

- The Docker host is on `192.168.1.100`
- I set up macvlan network
- I create a new container (App A) that uses port 1000 and give it the macvlan IP address `192.168.1.200`
- I then want to create a new container (App B) that uses port 2000, but also have the IP address `192.168.1.200`
- I can't create App B because `.200` is already in use

So my question is, is it possible to have two containers, both using `192.168.1.200`, exposing ports `1000` and `2000`, but not being accessible on `192.168.1.100`? In other words, made it look like `.100` and `.200` are physically separate machines?

Comment: Why do you want to use macvlan? And yes, in general, one machine may have as many IP's as you please, and one feature of macvlan is that you'll have separate L2 addressing for each container, so they can control IP's themself. So - why do  you want this, and have you tried what you suggest?

Comment: @vidarlo I'm not particularly wanting do this, but while I have used Docker before, I don't know much about it (having come from a VM background instead), so I've been playing around with Portainer and Docker at home. I noticed the bridge network mode, and ipvlan / macvlan modes and wondered if one could fire up two containers using an IP that wasn't the host's (maybe as a "this IP is where webapps live, this one is where databases live" sort of thing). Curiosity / wanting to learn more about network modes, you could say.

Comment: This worked for me [network_mode: service:web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43300613/multiple-docker-compose-container-single-ip)